# Ethers.js signTransaction with LedgerSigner doesn't work on Polygon (transaction.chainId/signature.v mismatch)

Tags: ethers.js, signature, ledger-nano-s

I'm trying to sign a simple transaction with ethers.js and my hardward wallet.
The code is fine since it's work well on ethereum mainnet, Binance Smart Chain and Fantom. But when I use this code to sign a transaction on Polygon I got the following error :
`Error: transaction.chainId/signature.v mismatch (argument="signature", value={"v":54,"r":"...","s":"..."}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=transactions/5.6.2)`

Minimum code to reproduce:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider('wss://....');
const signer = new LedgerSigner(provider, 'hid');
const chainId = (await provider.getNetwork()).chainId;

await signer.signTransaction({
        from: await signer.getAddress(),
        to: '0x....',
        value: BigNumber.from('1000000000000000000'),
        gasLimit: 21000,
        chainId: chainId,
        nonce: await signer.getTransactionCount('latest'),
        gasPrice: 100000000000,
    });
```

I really doesn't understand why.
Note that I've triple check that's the provider is the good one and the chainId is 137.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

For those who facing the same problem, I finally manage to make it work by following this post https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/1365#issuecomment-918817511

Comment: i'm facing the same issue but i really don't want to install frame, is there any other solution ?